How do I remove quotation marks from characters strings in Power BI?
I have unstructured data with quotation marks I'd like to remove using Power Query. Here's an example:
Have:
chrome has been “processing” for 8 mins now.
Want:
chrome has been processing for 8 mins now.
I've tried right clicking the column, choosing Replace Values, and in the 'Value to Find' block typing "
And in the 'Replace With' block I leave it blank.
This generates code like this:
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"PreviousAppliedStep","""","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Text String"}) 
However, when I apply it, the quotation marks are not removed from the string.
I have also tried several other variations:
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"PreviousAppliedStep",""","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Text String"})
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"PreviousAppliedStep","","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Text String"})
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"PreviousAppliedStep","'"'","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Text String"})
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"PreviousAppliedStep",'"',"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Text String"})
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"PreviousAppliedStep","'""'","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Text String"})
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"PreviousAppliedStep",'""',"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Text String"})
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"PreviousAppliedStep",#(0022),"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Text String"})
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"PreviousAppliedStep","#(0022)","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Text String"})
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"PreviousAppliedStep",U+0022,"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Text String"})

These options all either generate errors or else execute but without removing the quotation marks.
I know the challenge is that Power Query reads the " quotation mark as a separator to indicate where a text string starts and stops, but I don't know how to tell it that is the actual character I want removed.

You probably need to use double double quotes - ...PreviousAppliedStep", """", "",Replacer...

It depends on the type of your quotation mark. Are they "" or “” as these are different chars. Easiest way is to copy them from the preview window and place that in the replace dialogue.


Yes - these are 3 different kinds of quotation marks: “ " ” and I missed that before.  Thank you!

You show multiple types of quotation marks in your string.
In the Advanced Editor, you can add M-Code to replace multiple values at once.
@davidebacci suggested to use Text.Remove which provides a much simpler implementation than my original:
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WSs4oys9NVchILFZISk3NU3jUMKegKD85tbg4My/9UcNchbT8IgULhdzMvGKFvPxyPaXYWAA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    
    #"Replaced Quotes" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{
        {"Column1", each Text.Remove(_,{"""","“","”","‟"}), type text}})
in
    #"Replaced Quotes"

Source

#"Replaced Quotes"


Would this be better than a simple Text.Remove() for any reason?

@davidebacci Actually, Text.Remove would be better in my opinion. I knew there was something like that, but couldn't find it on my search. Do you want to change your answer, or should I change mine.

You can change yours Ron. As a seasoned M coder, I was struggling to understand your original solution and knew there was something simpler. Upvoted.

@davidebacci Done. Thanks. I was too focused on exploring the Table.ReplaceValue (and also the Splitter.SplitTextByAnyDelimiter function)
